# Getting error data not found using bootstrap datatable with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I used all possible dependencies available on net but couldn't able to solve the issue.
Back End code is written using ASP .NET and MVC returns Json data.

Below is my controller Code

```
var app = angular.module('myTaskFormApp', [])
app.controller('MyTaskController', function ($scope, $http, $location, $window) {
    $scope.TaskModel = {};
    $scope.message = '';
    $scope.result = 'colour-default';
    $scope.isViewLoading = false;
    $scope.List = null;
    $scope.List1 = null;
    var TaskNo = getQueryVariable('TaskNo');
    getallData();



//******=========Get All Resources=========******  

function getallData() {
    debugger;
    $http.get('/Dashboard/GetMyTasks?TaskNo=0').then(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.List = data.data;
        $('.dataTable-length').dataTable();
        }, function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.errors = [];
            $scope.message = 'Unexpected Error while saving data!!';
            console.log($scope.message);
        });
    };
});
```

I tried using datatable='ng' even that din't work.
Below is my HTML Code.
I'm getting data but at last I'm getting

> No data found

.
As I click the table to sort my data; all data is wiped out.
Anchor tag is also not working in the link. The link never hits the controller.

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered tab-pane dataTable-length" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>                              
            <th>Task Name</th>
                <th>Status</th>

                           </tr>

                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr ng-repeat="TaskModel in List | filter : paginate | filter:search" ng-class-odd="'odd'">
    <td>{{TaskModel.TaskName}}</td>
                                <td>{{TaskModel.Status}}</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[Im getting Data Not found at bottom of table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1AWjj.jpg)

Comment: It is most likely because your data is null/empty on initial load before it fetches data then to render your rows.

Comment: What i got to do?